# Text-Based Databases for Log Search?

Tags: full-text-search, bigdata, pytables

I am working on a large amounts of multidimensional **log data** at my company. I have to save and retrieve data from my text database really fast because there are amounts of data and if I build a search query(they are not so simple queries, i.e. between some dates etc.) it takes an efficient time.

Here are my points:

- We use **Lucene** but it doesn't fit out requirements.
- We don't use **SQL based databases** because it is overkill for storing large amount of log data and querying at this situation.
- We don't want to use **NoSQL databases** for log search because of our needs. We need a text based database.

We want to use [Pytables](http://www.pytables.org/moin) however **my question is that** I want to learn if there exists any other systems to store and search **fast** on **logs**?